# VSCode disabling Arduino compilation optimizations for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, compiler-optimization

With the default VSCode Arduino configuration the compiler is optimizing the generated code as fully optimized, so debugging using Cortex-Debug is pretty much impossible as code is optimized out and stepping jumps around everywhere.

Any pointers on how to disable all compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what development board you are using, I am using an Adafruit M0 Express. Adafruit has create board configuration options for I think is most of their SAMD boards. If you edit the boards.txt file. The image below is the standard board selector for VSCode Arduino for a Feather M0 Express, note the additional debug option. Adafruit has implemented a more extensive choice for optimizations on their M4 boards. Modeling from there example you could switch debug and optimizations separately.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOuUQ.png) to see example in VSCode

My Adafruit boards are found here:
C:\Users\GregTerrell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\adafruit\hardware\samd\1.5.11

The boards.txt default for 
  `.menu.debug.on.build.flags.debug=-g`

Change that to 
  `.menu.debug.on.build.flags.debug=-g -O0`

If you look at the build details the compiler command lines will have -Os and later you should find "-g -O0". GCC documentation states that if multiple occurrences of a flag are encountered, the last version of a compiler flag is used for the build.

Notes:

1. You will have to restart VSCode for the change to be effective.
2. Back up or take notes on how you change the boards.txt files. Updating your boards from within the Arduino IDE will overwrite your changes.