# Can't get past for/while loop in Arduino

Tags: c++, while-loop, arduino, delay, arduino-ide

New to Arduino, I have tried to make a for or a while loop to do a delay, instead of the `delay()` function. Have tried a LOT of values but the LED remains HIGH, it works if I use the `delay()` function. Note that I'm not going to use this code as delay, I just tried it and now I can't understand what goes wrong.
Board is a Nano Every, I use Arduino IDE, Fcpu = 8MHz.

```
const byte  ledPin = 13;
byte  ledState = HIGH; 
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
void loop() {
  unsigned long i = 0;
   // read the state of the switch into a local variable:
  //enaState = digitalRead(sw1);
  //dirState = digitalRead(sw2);
  
  while (i < 10000000)
  {
    i++;
  }
  //delay(1000);
  ledState ^= 1;
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  i = 0;
 
}
```

Comment: What do you initialize `ledState` with?

Comment: We are missing some of your code! It would be good to see what `ledState` is declared/initialised as. It would also help to see what `ledPin` is set to - is it intended to be the onboard LED? And what is in your `setup()` ? It is possible that the code gets stuck there too

Comment: Ok, added inits, note however, it works if I just use delay(1000);

Comment: Yes, ledPin is onboard LED.

Comment: I guess the compiler optimizes the while loop away. but even if not, you very underestimate the speed of the CPU

Comment: The loop is probably optimized away. Try `volatile unsigned long i = 0;`. But anyway, using an empty busy loop instead of `delay` is pretty pointless.

Comment: you need disable opzimizer of compiler otherwise the loop while (i < 10000000) { i++; } will be translate as i = 10000000;

Comment: @Jabberwocky Indeed, volatile works so it was removed by compiler. Thanks guys. How do I remove optimization, in platform.txt?

Comment: @MSA_R _How do I remove optimization?_: Don't, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496265/vscode-disabling-arduino-compilation-optimizations-for-debugging

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok

Comment: @MSA_R: but Jabberwocky is right, it is a not good idea. I'm sure there is a better alternative in the arduino libraries.

Comment: @Juraj I think you overestimate it, the Nano Every has a clock speed of 20 MHz, so it should take it around a half a second to iterate through the loop

Comment: @dmaxime I won't. This is interesting though, don't think I've encountered it before, probably because I have always used less aggressive optimization or just debugging. This got me question my own sanity :)

Comment: @AidanWelch It can be run at 20MHz, but default seems to be 16MHz. Accordingly to boards.txt;
nona4809.build.f_cpu=16000000L

Comment: @MSA_R That's entirely possible, my point was that at worst this delay should still be very noticeable

Answer (score 1):

Adding volatile to avoid being removed by optimization works.

```
volatile unsigned long i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The arduino compiler by default runs with all optimizations enabled, to reduce code size and improve speed. Since at least with the Arduino IDE, source-line debugging is not possible on the Arduino itself, this normally doesn't make a visible difference for development. The above code snippet is a rare example where it does.

How to disable optimization, if one really wants to do it, is described in this question: [VSCode disabling Arduino compilation optimizations for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496265/vscode-disabling-arduino-compilation-optimizations-for-debugging) (thanks @dmaxime).

Comment: @dmaxime Ups, sorry.